# VS Code Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (on Mac)

Tags: visual-studio-code, r-markdown, pandoc

I cannot set R Markdown on VS Code.

I already added the path for pandoc, but is still not recognized from VS Code.

settings.json

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
    "pandoc.useDocker": false,
    "pandoc.render.openViewer": true,
    "pandoc.executable": "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools",
    "quarto.path": "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/quarto",
    "chatgpt.lang": "en",
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        
    }
}
```

Do you know what else I can do?

I am using M1 Mac machine. The VS code extensions "R Markdown All in One" and "vcsode-pandoc" are enabled.

version

- platform       aarch64-apple-darwin20
- arch           aarch64
- os             darwin20
- system         aarch64, darwin20
- status
- major          4
- minor          3.1
- year           2023
- month          06
- day            16
- svn rev        84548
- language       R
- version.string R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
- nickname       Beagle Scouts

Thank you.

I am expecting a description how to solve the issue with the setup of Rmarkdown and pandoc.